# vim solarized in obj-c

Tags: xcode, vim, color-scheme

Not sure this is the default obj-c color in vim solarized or not but in xcode solarized I got a very more pleasant color than in Vim. Anyone know how to change the color in Vim to look same as Xcode ?

***Vim solarized***

[image: Vim obj-c solarized]

***Xcode solarized***

[image]

Comment: What about using the Solarized issue tracker?

Comment: I made another Solarized theme for Xcode trying to provide the same look as VIM does. https://github.com/stackia/solarized-xcode

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, the *colorscheme* (for you: solarized) provides a general palette of available colors / highlight attributes (like bold, italic, etc.) The *syntax scripts* (like for the `objc` filetype) then define syntax groups (like keywords, statements, variables, etc.) and link those to the highlight groups. Obviously, both the level of syntax parsing and the linking to colors is different in Vim vs. Xcode.

Whereas it's difficult to add more syntax differentiation (you'd have to extend the syntax script itself), you can easily (but tediously) influence which syntax group links to which highlight group.

For example, the `HiLink objcType Type` command in `syntax/objc.vim` establishes such a (default) link. To change that, use e.g.

```
:highlight link objcType Statement
```

For that task, the `:highlight` command lists all defined highlight groups, and `:syntax list` lists all syntax groups. Also, to find out which syntax group causes highlighting, it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.